# Registry path for current disc inside cdrom

Tags: windows, dvd, compact-disc

Where is located information about the current disc inside ROM in the registry?
I want to imitate the disc for one program.

Comment: Best solution is software to mount an iso image of your disc of choice>>>>>https://www.elby.ch/en/products/vcd.html

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thanks @Moab! I absolutely forgot about this way.